# How to write the shifted Chebyshev polynomials (the first kind) in mathematica?

Tags: special-functions, polynomials

Is it possible to write the shifted Chebyshev polynomials (the first kind) in Mathematica? The formula is:

$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^k 2^{n-2k-1}\frac{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{k}(2x-1)^{n-2k}$$

The output should be in a vector `{..., ..., ..., ... etc.}`
Thanks!!

Comment: By "vector", do you mean a vector of the first few polynomials?

Comment: yes please depend on n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
With[{m = 100}, 
    ChebyshevT[Range[m], 2 x - 1] == 
    Table[Sum[(-1)^k 2^(n - 2 k - 1) Binomial[n - k, k] (2 x - 1)^(n - 2 k) n/(n - k),
              {k, 0, Quotient[n, 2]}], {n, m}] // Expand]
   True
```

Comparing your formula with [formula 22.3.6 in Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_775.htm), we find that all you need to do is

```
ChebyshevT[Range[0, m - 1], 2 x - 1]
```

if you need an entire pile of these shifted polynomials.

Comment: Many thanks, put the output just word true not terms? I need few terms in vector depend on n, what about [n/2] is it greatest integer number?

Comment: The first snippet just shows that the simple expression is the same as your explicit sum. The second snippet is what you want for evaluation. Assign some positive integer to `m` and evaluate `ChebyshevT[Range[0, m - 1], 2 x - 1]` (e.g. `ChebyshevT[Range[0, 100 - 1], 2 x - 1]` to get a hundred of them).

Comment: Dear, 1) You mean I have to use ChebyshevT[Range[0, m - 1], 2 x - 1].?2) the first code With[{m = 100}, 
 ChebyshevT[Range[m], 2 x - 1] == 
   Table[Sum[(-1)^k 2^(n - 2 k - 1) Binomial[n - k, 
       k] (2 x - 1)^(n - 2 k) n/(n - k), {k, 0, Quotient[n, 2]}], {n, 
     m}] // Expand] for what then?3) [n/2] is it greatest integer number?